# Remove tooltips when creating an article

Tags: joomla

Say there is a menu item where a registered user to a website can create an article. When hovering the title (and all the form fields), a tooltip is shown, which consists of the title and the explanation. I have managed to hide the explanation, but I can't find a way to totally remove the whole tooltip. I really don't like the way the form goes up and down after hovering each field.

I have tried to add `JHTML::_('behavior.disable','tooltip')` in several files, but nothing happened. I also tried to comment `JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip')` wherever it was. I have searched everywhere, but can't find an answer that suits me.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Joomla? Can you link to a live example?

Comment: Which file have you tried adding the code to? Please bare in mind that there might be a template override for that file so the file will be in `templates/html/com_content/....` rather than `components/com_content/views/....`

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the class and using this in the CSS

```
.some_class {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```